# How to force users to link their check-ins to the current sprint?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, agile, scrum

In Visual Studio 2012, using TFS2012, it's already possible to require users to associate their Check-Ins with at least one work item.

But is it possible to limit the allowed work items to only those of the current sprint? (ie: limit them to one specific query folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to limit code and work item associations in TFS 2012 by enabling a work item query check in policy.

The TFS 2012 power tools includes a custom check-in policy for this type of policy.

1. Download the TFS 2012 power tools - [Check-In Policy Pack from the TFS 2012 Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775)
2. Enable the Work Item Query Policy— Enabling this policy allows administrators to specify that developers can associate their check-ins only with work items included in a specified work item query. For example, an administrator can create a team work item query that includes only work items in your sprint, which would effectively allow developers to associate only with the sprint work item.
3. It is important to ensure that all team members have the Power Tools installed, because check-ins for policies that a team member does not have will fail with a message indicating that Visual Studio Team Explorer was unable to find the check-in policy.